# CSS Floating and inline spans

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

I'm using `float:left` to have a span containing the user name floating to the right of the big numbers to the left.

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/d00ck/twcmfzo8/2/

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
.container {
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 15px width: 360px;
}
.position {
  clear: both;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ranking-position {
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
}
.ranking-tier {
  display: block;
}
.ranking-score {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">Dorothy Bradley</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">User Name</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>

  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">User Name</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'm obviously missing something important since I can't seem to make the span containing the "1000pts" legend to float to the right of the big number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change

```
.ranking-tier {
  display: block;
}
```

to this:

```
.ranking-name {
  display: block;
}
```

Something like this:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">Dorothy Bradley</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">User Name</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>

  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">User Name</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {

  font-family: arial;
}

.container{ 
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 15px
  width: 360px;
}

.position {
  clear: both;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.ranking-position {
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
}

.ranking-score {
  clear: both;
}

.ranking-name {
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/twcmfzo8/5/

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If you read my answer its pretty obvious why this code helps the OP. But thanks for your comment :-)

Comment: It's obvious to you and me; how about the OP? What about future viewers? Stack Overflow is about compiling a compendium of high quality questions and answers, not just about fixing one person's code. Feel free to take the [tour] again.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan from the link you gave me: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." I don't have time to be anymore specific. If the OP wants more explanation he can ask.

Comment: I would raise the point that you say "I don't have time to be more specific" which is fine, and understandable -- but then you spend this time you don't have, by arguing the point over comments.... which pretty much nullifies your original statement that you "don't have time".

Comment: @Martin Perhaps you're right - and maybe the correct wording is "I don't have the experience to explain it any further". Mike McCaughan linked me to the tour, where it states: "Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them." So if someone knows a way to improve my answer, feel free to edit it. Peace.

Comment: ooooh, you smoooth operator - Nice come back  `;-)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this One:

```
<div class="position">
  <div style="display:inline-block; float:left;">
  <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">Dorothy Bradley</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
  </div>
    <div style="float:right; display:inline-block;">
    <span class="ranking-score" style="position:relative; top:20px;">1000pts</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add a semicolon in the **.container** definition in CSS, after the *padding-bottom*. and add **float:right;** **margin-top:-20px;** in **.ranking_score**

Answer (score 0):

That's because the float is not tall enough to affect the three spans. You can try forcing some height

```css
.container {
  font-family: arial;
}
.position {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
}
.ranking-position {
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 60px; /* 16px * 1.25 * 3 */
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">Dorothy Bradley</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">User Name</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <span class="ranking-name">User Name</span>
    <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
    <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or wrap them inside a flock formatting context root:

```css
.container {
  font-family: arial;
}
.position {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.ranking-position {
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
}
.position > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <div>
      <span class="ranking-name">Dorothy Bradley</span>
      <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
      <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <div>
      <span class="ranking-name">User Name</span>
      <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
      <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="position">
    <span class="ranking-position">1</span>
    <div>
      <span class="ranking-name">User Name</span>
      <span class="ranking-tier">1rs Team All...</span>
      <span class="ranking-score">1000pts</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```